# Set deafult schema while querying in pgAdmin 4 with query tool

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Whenever i have to execute sql commands in `pgAdmin 4` i have to append `schema_name` with tables.
Eg :-

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.users //where myschema is schema name
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Is there any way to execute sql commands in `pgAdmin 4` without schema name, by setting a default schema in advance.

Some thing like this

```
SELECT * FROM programme
ORDER BY id ASC
```

- without specifying schema name with table.

Is there a way to set default schema in  `pgAdmin 4` for querying in sql tool?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:

```
SET search_path = my_schema, "$user", public; -- For current session only

ALTER ROLE your_role SET search_path = my_schema, "$user", public; -- Persistent, for role
```

You can also set it for whole database, same way as for role.

EDIT: Just to explain what this does - it will change where and in what order Postgres will search for objects matching object identifiers that did not get prefixed with schema name.

Comment: Maybe SO is making me lazy. It didn't occur to me just try this in the Query Tool window, until I saw this answer! In any case, thanks!

Comment: @ieXcept Those are names of schemas that you want PostgreSQL to look into when searching for objects (like table, view) if those aren't prefixed with schema name. `"$user"` will be replaced by your role name, assuming you have your own schema. Order of those is important, it goes from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `search_path` for server [image: Set Options in Register Server]

Answer (score 0):

You might need also to restart pgAdmin4 in order for the search_path to start working. At least it was my case.

A good double check if the search_path was set in pgAdmin4 is to go to:
*Login/Group Roles -> Right click on the user (by default it is 'postgres') -> Properties -> Parameters tab*. Here you should see your new parameter 'search_path' with the value 'your_schema_name'.